# Как происходит передача значения генератору?

Tags: javascript, генераторы, yield

Имеется следующий код:

```
function* gen() {
  let result = yield "2 + 2 = ?";
  console.log(result);
}

let generator = gen();
let question = generator.next().value;
generator.next(4); // 4
```

Как происходит передача значения генератору в данном случае, да и вообще, в целом? Ибо не до конца понятен этот момент, особенно в строке `generator.next(4);`, где, как я думаю, значение как раз должно передаваться в следующий `yield`, однако его нет.

Comment: что именно непонятно с `generator.next(4)`?

Comment: то, что он возвращает 4 на место `yield "2 + 2 = ?"`. в том плане, что метод `.next()` уже был вызван ранее и, как я предполагаю, данный вызов `generator.next(4);` должен обращаться к следующему оператору `yield` внутри генератора и передавать значение уже следующей переменной. в целом, нигде толком даже и не расписано, что именно представляет из себя `yield` "внутри", т.е. что он возвращает или не возвращает

Comment: [вот тут](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/yield) вполне расписано

Answer (score 0):

Когда вы только получаете `generator` то Вам нужно сначала как-бы "проинициализировать" его, вызвав `.next()` без параметров:

```
gen.next()
```

После этого можно передавать параметры:

```
function * generator () {
    const input_one = yield "Первое значение"
    return input_one
}

const gen = generator()

gen.next()
gen.next("Второе значение").value // Второе значение
```